# Props is not updating in class component React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-class-based-component

I am Traying to pass props as product data object on clicking on that product in  class  component in react  but element values are not getting assigned  the following code for which  am trying for plz help to solve this problem I am new at class component in react

```
class ProductList extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      product:undefined,
      productsList: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'Samsung Galaxy Note 10',
          category: 'Mobiles',
          country: 'Canada',
          price: 11500,
          currencyCode: 'CAD',
          productImage: require('./assets/img/product1.jpg'),
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          name: 'SkullCandy BT Inkd Plus',
          category: 'Bluetooth Headset',
          country: 'UK',
          price: 800,
          currencyCode: 'USD',
          productImage: require('./assets/img/product2.jpg'),
        }
      ],
    }
  }

  
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="ProductList">
          <ul id="products" className="products">
            {this.state.productsList.map((element, i) => (
              <li
                id={'product' + i}
                onClick={() => this.setState({ product: 'abc' })}
              >
                <img id={'image' + i} src={element.productImage} />
                <b>{element.name}</b>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div className="productComponent">
          {console.log(this.product)}
          <Product productProp={this.product} />
        </div>
      </>
    )
  }
}

export default ProductList
```

Comment: I think you just need to pass `this.state.product`, i.e. `<Product productProp={this.state.product} />`. If this isn't what you are asking about can you clarify more precisely what the issue is?

Answer (score 1):

Pass props as ***this.state.product*** instead of ***this.product***

```
<Product productProp={this.state.product} />
```